# How to find overlapping in collection using LINQ ( not duplicates but to find overlaps)

Tags: c#, linq, iequalitycomparer

```
List<StoreDetailDto> items = new List<StoreDetailDto>();

items.Add(new StoreDetailDto { StoreNumber = 2, WarehouseNumber = 4201, IsResolved = false, StoreName = "StoreEx", WarehouseName = "WarehouseEx1"});
items.Add(new StoreDetailDto { StoreNumber = 3, WarehouseNumber = 4201, IsResolved = false, StoreName = "StoreEx", WarehouseName = "WarehouseEx1"});
items.Add(new StoreDetailDto { StoreNumber = 6, WarehouseNumber = 4201, IsResolved = false, StoreName = "StoreEx", WarehouseName = "WarehouseEx1"});
items.Add(new StoreDetailDto { StoreNumber = 7, WarehouseNumber = 4201, IsResolved = false, StoreName = "StoreEx", WarehouseName = "WarehouseEx1"});
items.Add(new StoreDetailDto { StoreNumber = 9, WarehouseNumber = 4201, IsResolved = false, StoreName = "StoreEx", WarehouseName = "WarehouseEx1"});

items.Add(new StoreDetailDto { StoreNumber = 6, WarehouseNumber = 4202, IsResolved = false, StoreName = "StoreEx", WarehouseName = "WarehouseEx1"});
items.Add(new StoreDetailDto { StoreNumber = 7, WarehouseNumber = 4201, IsResolved = false, StoreName = "StoreEx", WarehouseName = "WarehouseEx1"});
items.Add(new StoreDetailDto { StoreNumber = 9, WarehouseNumber = 4203, IsResolved = false, StoreName = "StoreEx", WarehouseName = "WarehouseEx1"});
items.Add(new StoreDetailDto { StoreNumber = 9, WarehouseNumber = 4207, IsResolved = false, StoreName = "StoreEx", WarehouseName = "WarehouseEx1"});
```

I have collection above where there is a overlapping between store 6, 9 but store 7 is not overlap it's a duplicate. I am finding overlaps as such that same store with different warehouse.

in order to acheive that I am doing below:

```
var overlapDupStores = items.GroupBy(
    u => u.StoreNumber,
    u => { return u; },
    (key, g) => g.ToList())
  .ToList()
  .Where(cnt => cnt.Count() > 1);


foreach (var dpovl in overlapDupStores)
{
    var stores = dpovl.Where(g => g.IsResolved != true).GroupBy(u => new { u.StoreNumber, u.WarehouseNumber }).ToList();

    if (stores.Count() > 1)
    {
        response.OverlappingStores.AddRange(stores.SelectMany(gr => gr).ToList());
    }
}
```

I am first finding stores which are duplicates , it will have object inside object with duplicates of stores with count = 2 and then grouping by storenumber and warehouse number for different store and warehouse count will still be 2 but for same store and warehouse which is duplicate it will be count = 1 so i am finding count > 1 so i can find duplicates and check Isresolved not to pull same store again once it is resolved.

Below is the fiddle:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/TknnkJ

Comment: @Adriani6 it's not a duplicate of that.. it's opposite of what is being asked previously, that one was find duplicates and this one find overlapping ones

Comment: Using the Linq Except operator might yield a better solution for this problem.

Comment: My apologies in that case

Comment: @Adriani6 thank you, do you suggest any solution for the question please ?, also I think you downvoted my question

Comment: @VijenderReddyChintalapudi I didn't down-vote :)

Comment: @Phill can you suggest solution please ?

Comment: @GertArnold I edited the question, that requirement was tough to achieve with equality operator, but based on the below answer I edited it and wanted to acheive same thing on how he is doing below since it look clean way to do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one, using LINQ's `GroupBy().Select().Where()` to group and filter the list of objects based on the criteria that I assume you require, given the output you showed.

A description:

> `GroupBy()   =>` Groups the objects using the `StoreNumber`
>   property.
>  
>   `Select()    =>` Selects the objects where the
>   `IsResolved` property is `false`
>   `Where()     =>` Filters the
>   objects that have more than 1 elements with different
>   `WarehouseNumber`
>  
>   `SelectMany()=>` Flattens the Grouping, to have
>   all the matching objects in a sequential view

`OrderBy()` could be added, if required, to order the list on `StoreNumber` `ThenBy()` `WarehouseNumber`.

The `Duplicates` filter may not be correct, depending on the use case. It might be necessary to adapt it.

```
var Duplicates = 
    items.GroupBy(store => store.StoreNumber)
         .Select(grp => grp.Where(store => store.IsResolved == false))
         .Where(stores => stores.Count() > 1 && stores.Select(w => w.WarehouseNumber).Distinct().Count() == 1)
         .SelectMany(stores => stores)
         .ToList();

var Overlapping = 
    items.GroupBy(store => store.StoreNumber)
         .Select(grp => grp.Where(store => store.IsResolved == false))
         .Where(store => store.Count() > 1 && store.Select(w => w.WarehouseNumber).Distinct().Count() > 1)
         .SelectMany(stores => stores)
         .ToList();

Overlapping.ForEach(ovr =>
    Console.WriteLine($"{ovr.StoreNumber} " +
                      $"{ovr.WarehouseNumber} " +
                      $"{ovr.IsResolved} " +
                      $"{ovr.StoreName} " +
                      $"{ovr.WarehouseName}"));
```

This `Overlapping` List prints:

```
6 4201 False StoreEx WarehouseEx1
6 4202 False StoreEx WarehouseEx1
9 4201 False StoreEx WarehouseEx1
9 4203 False StoreEx WarehouseEx1
9 4207 False StoreEx WarehouseEx1
```

This `Duplicates` List prints:

```
7 4201 False StoreEx WarehouseEx1
7 4201 False StoreEx WarehouseEx1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think these queries do the job:

```
var overlaps =
    items
        .GroupBy(x => new { x.StoreNumber, x.WarehouseNumber })
        .GroupBy(x => x.Key.StoreNumber)
        .Where(x => x.Skip(1).Any())
        .Where(x => !x.Any(y => y.Any(z => z.IsResolved)))
        .SelectMany(x => x.SelectMany(y => y))
        .ToList();
```

[image: overlaps]

```
var duplicates =
    items
        .GroupBy(x => new { x.StoreNumber, x.WarehouseNumber })
        .GroupBy(x => x.Key.StoreNumber)
        .Where(x => !x.Skip(1).Any())
        .Where(x => x.First().Skip(1).Any())
        .Where(x => !x.Any(y => y.Any(z => z.IsResolved)))
        .SelectMany(x => x.SelectMany(y => y))
        .ToList();
```

[image: duplicates]

I used this source data:

```
var items = new List<StoreDetailDto>()
{
    new StoreDetailDto { StoreNumber = 2, WarehouseNumber = 4201, IsResolved = false, StoreName = "StoreEx", WarehouseName = "WarehouseEx1" },
    new StoreDetailDto { StoreNumber = 3, WarehouseNumber = 4201, IsResolved = false, StoreName = "StoreEx", WarehouseName = "WarehouseEx1" },
    new StoreDetailDto { StoreNumber = 6, WarehouseNumber = 4201, IsResolved = false, StoreName = "StoreEx", WarehouseName = "WarehouseEx1" },
    new StoreDetailDto { StoreNumber = 7, WarehouseNumber = 4201, IsResolved = false, StoreName = "StoreEx", WarehouseName = "WarehouseEx1" },
    new StoreDetailDto { StoreNumber = 9, WarehouseNumber = 4201, IsResolved = false, StoreName = "StoreEx", WarehouseName = "WarehouseEx1" },
    new StoreDetailDto { StoreNumber = 6, WarehouseNumber = 4202, IsResolved = true, StoreName = "StoreEx", WarehouseName = "WarehouseEx1" },
    new StoreDetailDto { StoreNumber = 7, WarehouseNumber = 4201, IsResolved = false, StoreName = "StoreEx", WarehouseName = "WarehouseEx1" },
    new StoreDetailDto { StoreNumber = 9, WarehouseNumber = 4203, IsResolved = false, StoreName = "StoreEx", WarehouseName = "WarehouseEx1" },
    new StoreDetailDto { StoreNumber = 9, WarehouseNumber = 4207, IsResolved = false, StoreName = "StoreEx", WarehouseName = "WarehouseEx1" },
};
```

It's worth noting that if 7 were to have a third record with a new `WarehouseNumber` that it would appear in the `overlaps` result and would include the duplicate there.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly. The following will give you want you want.

```
   var warehouseCountsByStore =
            from item in items
            group item by new { item.StoreNumber, item.WarehouseNumber } into store
            where store.Count() != 0
            select new
            {
                store.Key.StoreNumber,
                store.Key.WarehouseNumber,
                Count = store.Count()
            };

    var storesWithDuplicateWarehouses =
        from warehouse in warehouseCountsByStore
        where warehouse.Count != 1
        select new { warehouse.StoreNumber };

    var storesWithMultipleWarehouse =
        from item in items
        group item by new { item.StoreNumber } into store
        where store.Count() > 1
              && storesWithDuplicateWarehouses.Any(x => x.StoreNumber != store.Key.StoreNumber)
        select new
        {
            store.Key.StoreNumber
        };

    Console.WriteLine("Duplicates");
    foreach (var store in storesWithDuplicateWarehouses)
        Console.WriteLine(store.StoreNumber);

    Console.WriteLine("Overlap");
    foreach (var store in storesWithMultipleWarehouse)
        Console.WriteLine(store.StoreNumber);
```

Comment: I have created a fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/TknnkJ
it should show the overlap with all the columns like I have expected behaviour on the fiddle, any help appreciated and it is based on IsResolved Flag.